# Django iterate over ClearableFileInput widget field

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

currently have a model that has a `model.FileField()` attribute, and when rendering in my django template I just iterate over the fields, such as

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{field.errors}}
    <label for="{{field.auto_id}}">{{field.label}}</label>
    {{field}}
 {% endfor %}
```

However, when the template renders the `ClearableFileInput` widget, I want to add some space between the `href` and the checkbox for clearing the widget. Any ideas on how to access those specific "parts" of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the default `ClearableFileInput` and set those rendering attributes to your taste

```
class MyClearableInput(ClearableFileInput):
    template_with_initial = '%(initial_text)s: %(initial)s %(clear_template)s<br />%(input_text)s: %(input)s'
    template_with_clear = '%(clear)s <label for="%(clear_checkbox_id)s">%(clear_checkbox_label)s</label>'
    url_markup_template = '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'
```

I've put the initial attributes, but you have to change them to reflect your desired output. It's pretty self-explanatory. Then in your form, override the widgets to use this class using the `Meta/widgets` attribute.