# customise django widget in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have standard model form in django with Imagefield and standard widget. It made me such output on the page:

`Currently: <a href="/media/qwe/Tulips.jpg">qwe/Tulips.jpg</a> <input id="image-clear_id" name="image-clear" type="checkbox" /> <label for="image-clear_id">Clear</label><br />
Change: <input id="id_image" name="image" type="file" />`

I want to place outputs of this widget in different parts of page. How can I cut it in templates.
If there is a way to use part of the output in template like {{form.name_of_field.label}} or {{form.name_of_field.errors}}

I've tried different names but no use

There must be a way to use them apart.

Comment: Just find this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191940/django-iterate-over-clearablefileinput-widget-field?rq=1) with overriding the default widget ClearableFileInput. Any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

And yet another one who needs form styling.

I would recommend to use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<form method='POST' action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.first_name |add_class:"customCSS1 customCSS2" }}
 {{ form.second_name |add_class:"customCSS3 customCSS4" }}
</form>
{{ form.media.js }}
```

with this plugin you can style the form as you wish. All Css classes work. You can put each form field wherever you want on the Page. Is that what you are looking for? Your question is a bit misleading.

Hope that helps if not leave a comment :)

Comment: This is not exactly the  answer of my question, but I reread users manual for  widget_tweaks. It is very useful thing especially for styling. I think I will use overriding default widget here, beacause I need to take only several part of the widget and widget_tweaks only add classes and arguments to html